# Insert android spinner elements from another class

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner, android-spinner

I have 2 classes AddCategory and SaveData. AddCategory contains a edit text and a button ADD. Second class contains a spinner and some edit texts. I want to add Some data from 1st class to second class that is Edit text input to Spinner. How can I parse value from first class to second class? Please explain with example..

**ADD CATEGORY CLASS**

```
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            call();     

        }

    });

}

public void call()
{
    cat=edtCategory.getText().toString();

    list.add(cat);    <<<<<*** I want to read and insert this arraylist into spinner in SAVE DATA class ****>>>>>>

}
```

}

**SAVE DATA CLASS**

```
Spinner category;
Button btnSave;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.income_add);

    Intent i=getIntent();

    category=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner01);

    btnSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
```

//* I put a Log here to read arraylist from ADD CATEGORY class, getting null value here. I need to read the arraylist and insert into spinner* //

}

Comment: you can share value using static variable. and add it to your spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String edittextvalue=yourEdittext.getText().toString();

Intent i = new Intent(AddCategory.this, SaveData.class);   
i.putStringArrayListExtra("list", list);
startActivity(i);
```

In SaveData class:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("list");
ArrayAdapter<String> ad =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,layoutId, list);
spinner.setAdapter(ad);
```

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem completely. I have edited the question with my code, please check it and help me to solve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values from AddCategory Class  to SaveData Class with the help of 
**Shared preferences**

**Use this to "put" the file (In AddCategory class)...**

```
Intent i = new Intent(AddCategory.this, SaveData.class);   
String keyIdentifer  = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

**Then , to retrieve the value try something like:(In SaveData class)**

```
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```